# What's the difference between "(UIElement.Property)" and "Property" in Animation

Tags: wpf, animation

In a `DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames` I could write either of these:

```
Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)"
Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
```

and the effect is appaently indistinguishable to me. Is there any case where it's a must to use parentheses and write `UIElement.` before the Property name or I can always forget those?

Comment: According to the explanation in [PropertyPath for Animation Targets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/propertypath-xaml-syntax#propertypath-for-animation-targets) the parentheses would only be necessary for attached properties (though the lookup also works for regular dependency properties).

Comment: @Clemens, in that case I'd have to replace `UIElement.` with the name of `Parent.`? For example, instead of writing `(UIElement.Row)` I'd have to write `(Grid.Row)` if I wanted to change the position in the `Grid`, right?

Comment: Yes, you should use the "owner type", i.e. the type that registered the property, e.g. class Grid for Grid.Row.